# redirecting openshift rhcloud domain to custom domain for SEO purposes

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

Openshift application url: `example.rhcloud.com`

Custom domain: `example.com`

I came across this [link](http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2012/09/11/search-engine-friendly-redirects-for-custom-domains-on-openshift-using-a-htaccess-file.html) and added the redirection rule. However, I can not access `example.rhcloud.com` now. My custom domain is `www.example.com`.

To avoid duplicate content problems, I tried this redirection.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Uncomment the following lines to force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Redirect Https traffic to Http
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 


# Redirect openshift rhcloud domain to custom domain
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.rhcloud.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why is `example.com` not redirecting to `ww.example.com`? How do I fix this?

Also, I see that since I have https to http redirection and non www to www redirection, my blog has been loading slow. How can I reduce it to lesser number of rules?

Edit:

In chrome:
[image]

In Firefox:

> The page isn't redirecting properly, Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.     This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: You may be thinking backwards?? Do you not want to redirect www.example.com to example.rhcloud.com? Isn't example.rhcloud.com where your site is? If this is the case, you do not need a redirect. Just set a CNAME from one to the other.

Comment: @closetnoc: I have the Cname set up. However I do not want google to index my content on different urls.This way my content is going to be available on `example.rhcloud.com` and `example.com`. I want my content to be at `example.com` only.

Comment: Could you please check the link I mentioned in the post once?That explains why i am trying this

Comment: I would set it up so that `example.com` is how people know you and use a canonical tag on all of your pages pointing to `example.com/whatever-your-page-is` so that Google and search engines will get it right without duplicate content issues.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. In that case, what are all these pages where I need to set the canonical tag? In my header.php I guess? and apart from that?

Comment: It still sounds backwards to me. We do these kinds of set-ups here all the time.

Comment: Okay , I will take the canonical approach then:) Sounds better to me as well. Do you mind explaining a little bit on where exactly I need to add this tag apart from header.php?

Comment: Here is a link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Look for the header *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element* which gives you an example. It would go in the head tag for every page and simply point to itself using the preferred domain. So `example.com/blah.html` would point to `example.com/blah.html` and when someone gets to it using `example.my-provider.com/blah.html` will have `example.com/blah.html` as the canonical link.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. One last call, when you say, it would go in head tag for every page, you mean that I will need to add it to header.php only right and then it would be in the head section of all my blog pages by itself and I do not need to add it everywhere apart from header.php, Is that right?

Comment: Now that I think about it- I think I understand why the redirect. Not a bad option. Set-up the CNAME from `example.com` to `example.myprovider.com` and test getting to your site `example.com` without the redirect. If that works, test getting to your site via `example.myprovider.com` with the redirect and see if that works. It is possible you are getting into a redirect loop in which case we would need to look at the redirect again.

Comment: I am old-school and do not use PHP or Wordpress or anything like it. I wrote my own CMS using another language. So I am not sure how that would work.

Comment: Sure, I will try that and be right back here :)

Comment: @closetnoc: That needs to be done at hosting side only. Now?

Comment: "However, I can not access your-techchick.rhcloud.com now" - what is the purpose of accessing `your-techchick.rhcloud.com`. (The reason for the redirect is presumably so that `your-techchick.rhcloud.com` is _not_ accessible?)

Comment: No, I was making changes so probably that's the reason that you could not access it. your-techchick.rhcloud.com is accesible and is indexed by search engines. I do not want my content to be available at two different domain.it can cause duplicate content penalty so to avoid it, I want to redirect your-techchick.rhcloud.com to yourtechchick.com @w3d

Comment: Now, when I try to redirect it, It gives me too many redirects

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't access your site - I was quoting you (3rd paragraph in your question) - this implies that you _need_ access to `example.rhcloud.com`?

Comment: I meant that after adding that particular redirection rule from the link, I could not.

Answer (score 2):

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

If you are redirecting from one completely different domain to another then you would not expect to be able to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the target. For example, the above would result in `example.rhcloud.com` being redirected to `www.example.rhcloud.com` - which is not the desired result. Then the following redirect to your actual domain would never match.

All you need is something like the following *before* the "WordPress" directives. Note that the order of directives in .htaccess is important.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This simply redirects to your desired domain if you are not already at your desired domain. There is no need for an explicit canonical www redirect, or checking for HTTPS (your new domain is not accessible by HTTPS).

Clear your browser cache before testing (301 redirects are cached). Change the `302` in the above to `301` when you are sure it's working OK.

So, in summary, your complete .htaccess file should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I am using incognito window. I used the one that you mentioned, It gives 503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: Also favicon.ico:1 `GET http://www.example.com/favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)` This is what I get in console.

Comment: You'll need to keep closing and opening the incognito window. It's easier to keep the "Object Inspector" open > Network tab > "Disable cache". The above directive cannot result in a 503. If you are getting a 503 there is likely to be a conflict with other directives. I notice you still have an HTTPS redirect? The above should replace all your redirects. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sure. Also, are you sure that setting wordpress url and site url to www.yourtechchick.com is not the conflict here?

Comment: Sorry, there was a silly mistake in my code... Should have been `RewriteRule` not `RewriteCond` - corrected.

Comment: your-techchick.rhcloud.com has a redirect loop now. I have attached the snapshot in question.Please check. @w3d

Comment: It appears to be redirecting to `https://example.rhcloud.com/` - note the HTTPS - where is it getting that from? (I've added a summary of what your complete .htaccess file should look like.)

Comment: yes, I used exactly the same .htaccess file. Ho should I know where is HTTPS coming from?Where should I check?

Comment: How can I block https redirects?

Comment: (That HTTPS might be a red herring.) However, there certainly seems to be _something else_ going on here. If all you have in .htaccess are the above directives then that can not possibly result in a redirect loop. Is there anything else in the configuration at `rhcloud.com` or in WordPress itself?

Comment: In wp-config.php, `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com');` and
`define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com');`

Comment: Besides this, There is nothing extra anywhere.I have exactly the same .htaccess as you have.

Comment: Also, I could not see, where did you notice this https thing? Anywhere in snapshot?

Comment: The HTTPS might have be a problem my end (browser history perhaps) - which is why I mentioned possible "red herring" - sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, In that case https is not the problem. What could it be then. It's driving me really crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure - there would seem to be _something else_ going on? Is the DNS setup correctly? You appear to have both an `A` record as well as `CNAME` - is that correct? Incidentally, have you just removed this redirect, since it's not trying to redirect anymore?

Comment: Yes, I did remove it now. Since it was not working, shall I add it back?

Comment: Well, for some unknown reason it was redirecting back to `example.rhcloud.com` instead of `www.example.com` - which would seem to be impossible from the directives posted above. What version of Apache are you using? What is `rhcloud.com`? How is it different to a "normal" server?

Comment: rhcloud.com is the CName provided by OpenSHift hosting .I am unaware of apache version.I do not really have to deal with apache directly.

Comment: Shall I wait for your response?

Comment: Well, I'm at a bit of a loss to be honest. The thought had crossed my mind whether `HTTP_HOST` was not set correctly (although that doesn't really make sense) - but even if it wasn't it should still redirect away from `example.rhcloud.com`?

Comment: As far as I remember, while setting up the cname , host part of it was set to www and target to your-techchick.rhcloud.com

Comment: The CNAME looks setup correctly. (Although I'm still not sure about that `A` record?) The `HTTP_HOST` is a server variable that Apache makes available from the _host_ header in the HTTP request sent from the client. ie. it should be set to `example.rhcloud.com` when accessing via `http://example.rhcloud.com` and `example.com` when accessing via `http://example.com`. However, if this is going through a proxy then this _might_ get changed?!

Comment: I could only understand bit of what you said. I had DNS provider support team set this up for me. Do I need to check with them about something?