# Redirection rule not working in .htacces

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I have added the following rule to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I suppose it says that if url is not `example.com`, redirect it to `www.example.com`.

I need to do this as I have a Cname `example.rhcloud.com` and is mapped to `www.example.com`. But I still can access `example.rhcloud.com` and is being indexed by Google as well. I certainly do not want my data to be available on 2 different domains and want `example.rhcloud.com` to be redirected to www.example.com

With above rewrite rule, it does nothing and gives access to `example.rhcloud.com`.

*I also tried using*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.rhcloud.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it says too many redirects as it try and retry to connect to `example.rhcloud.com`.

How do I have this redirect work?

Also, If that makes any difference, I have added WordPress URL and site URL set to `www.example.com` only.

Comment: Can you try 
 `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your-techchick.rhcloud.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] `

Comment: Is this any different to [your other question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85787/redirecting-openshift-rhcloud-domain-to-custom-domain-for-seo-purposes)?

Comment: Sorry but please do not repeat questions. We have several ways of bumping old questions through quality editing and running bounty's. If the questions are unrelated to one another then please edit your question and ensure the question is unique.

Comment: Sure. Shall I delete this one?